# Thermalising a sub-system of a larger, interacting system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, research-level, quantum-information

I'm considering a joint system consisting of a spin-1/2 particle (qubit) and a spin-l particle (reference) coupled via a Hamiltonian $H_0$.
At a certain point I want to couple the qubit to a bosonic bath. I tried to use the interaction Hamiltonian
$$
H_{int} = \sigma_x\otimes\mathbb{1}\otimes\sum_k g_k(a_k^\dagger+a_k),
$$
where $\sigma_x$ is the usual Pauli operator acting on the qubit, the identity acts on the reference, and the $a_k^\dagger$ and $a_k$ are the creation/annihilation operators of the bath.

After setting up an appropriate master equation and numerically solving it, the problem is that this coupling, despite the identity on the reference, instantly affects the reference as well as the qubit, with the joint system approaching the Gibbs state given by $H_0$. What I was expecting instead was a much more indirect thermalisation of the reference, in which initially only the qubit is affected and then, with a delay, the reference reacts to the qubit's changed state.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way in which I can couple the two systems to the bath which achieves such dynamics?

Comment: That's an interesting effect indeed. Does it depend on the relative strength of $H_0$ compared to the $g_k$s? What is the form of $H_0$?

Comment: The relative strength of $H_0$ and $g_k$ only affects how fast the thermalisation happens but qualitatively it's the same. The form of $H_0$ is
$$
H_0 = S_z \otimes L_z + \mathbb{1}\otimes L_y
$$
where the $S$ and $L$ are the angular momentum operators.